# Как называется такая "инверсия" понятий?

Tags: тропы, фигуры

Есть ли какое-то специальное название для литературного приёма, использованного в следующих примерах из творчества В.С. Высоцкого (выделено ниже).

> И **брызнули слёзы, как камни**, из раненых скал.
>  И брызнули камни,
>   как слёзы, из раненых скал.

(Когда я услышал эту песню, в ней были обе строки и это производило сильное впечатление. Сейчас больше находится записей без второй строки.) Вторую строку можно рассматривать как метафору, но в первой использован другой приём. Что это?

И ещё пример с такой (такой ли?) перестановкой:

> А мы всё ставим каверзный **ответ** — 
>  И не находим нужного **вопроса**.

Я посмотрел метонимию, катахрезу, хиазм; Гугл ещё предлагал аллогизм, но всё кажется, что это не то.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю, начать нужно с главного художественного приёма, на котором основано всё стихотворение (песня). Это **развёрнутое олицетворение**, отсылающее нас к пушкинскому "Эху". Как и у Пушкина, эхо символизирует голос поэта, отзывающегося на раны и боли окружающего мира. Этот голос оказывает духовную поддержку словом правды. Но итог стихотворений разный. У Пушкина эхо остаётся жить, хоть ему и «нет отзыва». У Высоцкого «эхо связали, и в рот ему всунули кляп», а затем «топтали» и, наконец, «к утру расстреляли». Лишь онемевшее горное пространство отозвалось на гибель эха: «…И брызнули слёзы, как камни из раненых скал…» Поэт ХХ века знает и испытывает на себе продолжение трагедии; его уже не просто притесняют, преследуют, его лишают слова, его уничтожают. Эхо теперь – живое существо, овеществлённая душа. Трагедия воображаемая воплощается в жестокой реальности современности, не теряя от этого оттенка всегдашности происходящего. Такой приём соединения двух реальностей - фантастической и настоящей - называется  в литературе **гротеском**. Чаще всего гротеск создаёт абсурдные ситуации, комические, а у Высоцкого - трагические.

Метафоризация здесь доведена не до конца, поэт как бы предлагает нам воспринимать всё и в прямом смысле (камни падают от выстрелов), и в переносном (скалы плачут - брызнули слёзы, как камни). «К утру расстреляли притихшее горное, горное эхо, // и брызнули слезы, как камни, из раненых скал...». Если бы было просто: Камни – как слезы, было бы обычное сравнение, а слезы (гор) – как камни, камнями плачут скалы, и эти слезы каменные: по сути тавтология, но тавтология поэтически выразительная.

Сочетание "брызнули камни" - всеми узнаваемая метафора, а вот две строки рядом, в обеих сравнения и повтор "брызнули" - это всё-таки **синтаксический параллелизм**, и не только синтаксический, но и семантический. Я склонна видеть здесь всё-таки **хиазм**, хотя Вы его и отвергли.

**Хиазм - перевёрнутый параллелизм** "Все во мне, и я во всём" (Ф. Тютчев); обычно со значением антитезы: "Мы едим, чтобы жить, а не живём, чтобы есть".

От других мне хвала - что зола,
От тебя и хула - похвала.
(А. Ахматова)

У Высоцкого встречается не так уж редко:

Я дышу – и значит я люблю,
Я люблю – и значит я живу.

Так что здесь сложная фигура речи - хиазм + гротеск. Можно сказать **"гротескный хиазм"**

```
      А мы всё ставим каверзный ответ — 

      И не находим нужного вопроса.
```

Здесь просматривается **нарушение (расширение) лексической сочетаемости**. Ср.
у Б. Пастернака: "Февраль. Достать чернил и плакать! Писать о феврале навзрыд…"
"Писать навзрыд" = писать + плакать навзрыд, сливаются два действия в одно, но одно явное, записанное, а второе "в уме",две фразы - перед метафорой её прямое значение, в результате как бы речевая ошибка, нарушена сочетаемость слов, но не логика мысли.

У Высоцкого:

Поэты ходят пятками по лезвию ножа и режут в кровь свои **босые души.**

Собственно, и предыдущие строки, нами разбираемые, тоже подходят под это:

…И брызнули камни, как слезы, из раненых скал.(а перед этим - "брызнули слёзы", правильное сочетание).

И здесь: ставим ответ, находим вопрос - нарушена сочетаемость противопоставленных 
 слов. Понятия «вопрос» «ответ» меняются местами. По мнению В. Высоцкого, мучивший Гамлета (а вслед за ним и все человечество) вопрос «быть или не быть» не является самым трудным и важным, самый нужный вопрос еще не найден, не сформулирован. Финал стихотворения открыт, Высоцкий обозначает проблему, но не пытается ее решить, открытость финала, его принципиальная недосказанность задана уже в начале стихотворения «Я только малость объясню в стихе / На все я не имею полномочий». Гамлет, которого Высоцкий играл, не думает, быть ему или не
 быть, он знает, что хорошо жить. Как ни странно, вопрос, который всем ясен что быть лучше и жить надо все равно стоит перед определенными людьми всю историю человечества. Вот что Гамлета мучает: значит, что-то не в порядке, если ясно, что жить лучше, а люди все время решают этот вопрос. Вопрос в том, чтобы не вставало этого вопроса.

Comment: Хиазм - слишком общее понятие, самые разные приемы можно назвать хиазмом. Например: То, как зверь, она завоет, то заплачет, как дитя. Это тоже хиазм, а всего-то переставлены позиции сравнений. У Высоцкого "хиазм" особый, Вы можете привести из литературы точно такой пример? Что-нибудь вроде следующего: Дым развеялся, как мечты, Мечты развеялись, как дым.

Comment: Ну, нет, Вы сами сказали, что у Высоцкого особый хиазм. Есть и классический, я его приводила: Я дышу – и значит я люблю, Я люблю – и значит я живу. А здесь больше классический синтаксический параллелизм с анафорой и эпифорой: И брызнули слёзы, как камни, из раненых скал.//И брызнули камни, как слёзы, из раненых скал. Но перекрёст-то есть: слёзы как камни//камни как слёзы. Автора вроде бы интересовал именно этот перекрёст, а не сам параллелизм конструкции.

Comment: И вообще, по-моему, здесь интересен  не синтаксический перекрёст, а семантический, ведущий к метафоричности, но и она необычна, поэтому пришлось идти от идеи, от логики мысли, сочетаемости слов.

Comment: Людмила, спасибо. Ваш ответ тоже очень понравился.

Comment: Людмила, Вы не ответили на мой вопрос: Вы можете привести из литературы точно такой пример, как у Высоцкого? Вот Вы не считаете, что это нечто новое, тогда хотелось бы конкретно увидеть именно этот хиазм у него или у других писателей/поэтов. В конце концов, сочинить обычный хиазм легко. Я бы их разделила на семантические и грамматические. Семантический: я и искусство, связанные понятия. Берем подходящий глагол и получаем: Любите не себя в искусстве, а искусство в себе. Грамматический: Прекрасна, как ангел небесный, как демон, коварна и зла. Таких примеров не сосчитать, но мне интересен один.

Comment: Не очень поняла, чего Вы от меня хотите - чтобы я продублировала точно такой же приём? Но ведь здесь их несколько, не только хиазм, но и чистый параллелизм, и анафора с эпифорой. О каком "именно этом" хиазме вы говорите? Есть два вида хиазмов: в одном случае элементы высказывания просто воспроизводятся в зеркальном порядке (у Блока: «Вот лицо возникает из кружев, Возникает из кружев лицо»), в другом  синтаксические связи меняются на обратные,перестановка и частей слож. предложения,  и сл.-соч. («Не начальник жены, а жена начальника», «не исторический роман, а романтическая история»).

Comment: Это антиметабола. Чистый хиазм:«Если нельзя разлучить мужа и жену, то еще более не во власти человека разлучить пастыря и паству. Где я, там и вы, а где вы, там и я. Мы одно тело. А тело от головы, как и голова от тела, не отделяются».Здесь хиастически переставлены слова «я» и «вы», «тело» и «голова». Хиазм подчеркивает нерасторжимость и симметрию отношений пастыря и паствы. У нас же "слёзы как камни//камни как слёзы" - симметрия отношений слёзы-камни. Разве не хиазм?

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, что в приведенных примерах использованы не одни и те же приемы, хотя и похожие.

1) **И брызнули слёзы, как камни, из раненых скал. И брызнули камни, как слёзы, из раненых скал.**

**Я посмотрела в Сети разбор Высоцкого,** но вот что интересно. У некоторых пользователей возникают сомнения, что это действительно две строки, а не варианты одной. В школьном разборе учащиеся анализируют текст, но при этом оставляют только  "камни, как слезы", другой строки у них нет.

**Но эти строки все-таки есть.** Так как готового решения не нашлось, попробуем описать художественный прием как принципиально новый.

**Мне кажется, это может выглядеть примерно так.**

Есть обычное сравнение, всем понятное: **брызнули камни, как слезы**. Далее автор использует инверсию, теперь уже это именно слёзы, а не камни, они только похожи на камни. Сравнение как бы переходит в метафору. Инверсия перемешивает понятия, мы уже не различаем их,  и такой прием усиливает эффект, содержит градацию образа.

В результате получается **сложный художественный прием:**  сравнение, инверсия сравнения и метафоры, градация художественного образа. **Интересно было бы найти в литературе что-нибудь похожее.**

**Примечание.** Однако в тексте эти строки идут не в таком порядке, то есть метафора стоит на первом месте, а потом переходит в сравнение.

2) **А мы всё ставим каверзный ответ — И не находим нужного вопроса.**

Это тоже малоизвестный прием, но здесь используется инверсия слов с противоположным значением, но в результате  тоже присутствует  смешение понятий.

Похоже **на оксюморон,** но отличается от него именно инверсией, обычно оксюморон — это просто совмещение несовместимого (сравнить: весело грустить).

Может быть, это **особый вид оксюморона (инверсированный).**

Comment: Спасибо, интересно! *Однако в тексте эти строки идут не в таком порядке* — [вот здесь, последние 15 сек.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_IqN7VeR9S8) именно в таком порядке, и у меня в детстве на пластинке в таком было, а в другом я не слышал. Такой порядок усиливает эффект неожиданности после обычного сравнения.